# SQL - Sum amounts daily from non-daily data

Tags: sql-server

I have a Account Balance History table containing `ACCT_ID`, `EFFDATE`, and `AMT`. `ACCT_ID` and `EFFDATE` are PK. A new `AMT` is only recorded when it changes, which doesn't happen every day.

What I want to do is create a query that will give me daily totals for each of the last 5 days where `EFFDATE` is less <= one of the 5 calendar dates. Then problem I'm having is that not I don't have a Date table to queue off of to find `AMT`.

I am unable to alter the database in any way.

Here is sample data:

```
+---------+------------+------+
| ACCT_ID |  EFFDATE   | AMT  |
+---------+------------+------+
|    1112 | 12/30/2018 |  500 |
|    1112 | 12/25/2018 |  675 |
|    1112 | 12/21/2018 |  187 |
|    1112 | 12/19/2018 |  332 |
|    1112 | 12/10/2018 |   92 |
|    1112 | 12/3/2018  |  300 |
|    2223 | 12/29/2018 |  225 |
|    2223 | 12/20/2018 |  100 |
|    2223 | 12/11/2018 |  525 |
|    3334 | 12/31/2018 | 1000 |
|    3334 | 12/20/2018 |  600 |
|    3334 | 12/14/2018 |  490 |
|    3334 | 12/1/2018  |  350 |
|    4445 | 12/20/2018 |  300 |
|    4445 | 12/19/2018 |  250 |
|    4445 | 12/12/2018 |  200 |
|    4445 | 12/9/2018  |  150 |
|    4445 | 12/6/2018  |  100 |
|    4445 | 12/1/2018  |   50 |
+---------+------------+------+
```

I can successfully sum `AMT` for the most recent day with this script:

```
SELECT sum(amt) from (
select  

ACCT_ID, EFFDATE, AMT, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by acct_id order by effdate desc) Rn

from BALHIST
) q where q.Rn = 1
```

Assuming today is 1/1/19, how can I get total balance for Today and the last 5 days?

EDIT: Expected Results

```
+------------+----------+
|    Date    | Sum(AMT) |
+------------+----------+
| 12/31/2018 |     2025 |
| 12/30/2018 |     1625 |
| 12/29/2018 |     1800 |
| 12/28/2018 |     1625 |
| 12/27/2018 |     1625 |
| 12/26/2018 |     1625 |
| 12/25/2018 |     1625 |
|            |          |
| 12/20/2018 |     1282 |
| 12/19/2018 |     1597 |
| 12/18/2018 |     1307 |
+------------+----------+
```

Manual calculation sample:

```
12/31/2018: ([1112,12/30/2018] + [2223,12/29/2018] + [3334,12/31/2018] + [4445,12/20/2018]) = 2025

12/26/2018: ([1112,12/21/2018] + [2223,12/20/2018] + [3334,12/20/2018] + [4445,12/20/2018]) = 1675
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87863/discussion-on-question-by-sleven-sql-sum-amounts-daily-from-non-daily-data).

Answer (score 1):

This gives you the expected output for a given date range.  May not be the most elegant though, but it includes an example of creating a Date table on the fly, although for large date ranges it will perform poorly.

```
DECLARE @Accounts TABLE
    (
    ACCT_ID INT NOT NULL
    , EFFDATE DATE NOT NULL
    , AMT INT NOT NULL
    )

;WITH CTE_Values AS
    (
    SELECT ACCT_ID
        , EFFDATE
        , AMT
    FROM (VALUES (1112, '12/30/2018', 500)
                , (1112, '12/25/2018', 675)
                , (1112, '12/21/2018', 187)
                , (1112, '12/19/2018', 332)
                , (1112, '12/10/2018',  92)
                , (1112, '12/3/2018', 300)
                , (2223, '12/29/2018', 225)
                , (2223, '12/20/2018', 100)
                , (2223, '12/11/2018', 525)
                , (3334, '12/31/2018',1000)
                , (3334, '12/20/2018', 600)
                , (3334, '12/14/2018', 490)
                , (3334, '12/1/2018', 350)
                , (4445, '12/20/2018', 300)
                , (4445, '12/19/2018', 250)
                , (4445, '12/12/2018', 200)
                , (4445, '12/9/2018', 150)
                , (4445, '12/6/2018', 100)
                , (4445, '12/1/2018',  50)
        ) AS P (ACCT_ID, EFFDATE, AMT)
    )
INSERT INTO @Accounts
(ACCT_ID, EFFDATE, AMT)
SELECT ACCT_ID, EFFDATE, AMT
FROM CTE_Values 

/***************************************************/

DECLARE @EndDate DATE = '12/31/2018'
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = DATEADD(DAY, -5, @EndDate)

;WITH CTE_Dates AS
    (
    SELECT 0 AS Number
        , @EndDate AS TheDay
    UNION ALL
    SELECT D.Number + 1 AS Number
        , DATEADD(DAY, (D.Number + 1) * -1, @EndDate) AS TheDay
    FROM CTE_Dates AS D
    WHERE DATEADD(DAY, (D.Number + 1) * -1, @EndDate) >= @StartDate
    )
, CTE_EveryAccountEveryDay AS
    (
    SELECT A.ACCT_ID
        , D.TheDay 
    FROM CTE_Dates AS D
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ACCT_ID FROM @Accounts) AS A
    )
, CTE_AccountBalances AS
    (
    SELECT E.ACCT_ID
        , E.TheDay
        , A.AMT 
        , PriorAMT = LAG(AMT) OVER (PARTITION BY E.ACCT_ID ORDER BY E.TheDay) 
    FROM CTE_EveryAccountEveryDay AS E
        LEFT OUTER JOIN @ACcounts AS A ON A.ACCT_ID = E.ACCT_ID AND A.EFFDATE = E.TheDay    
    )   
, CTE_WrappingItUp AS
    (
    SELECT ACCT_ID
        , TheDay
        , AMT = COALESCE(AMT, PriorAMT, (SELECT TOP (1) AMT FROM @Accounts WHERE ACCT_ID = B.ACCT_ID AND EFFDATE <= B.TheDay ORDER BY EFFDATE DESC))
    FROM CTE_AccountBalances AS B
    )
SELECT TheDay AS EFFDATE
    , SUM(AMT) AS AMT_Total
FROM CTE_WrappingItUp
GROUP BY TheDay
ORDER BY TheDay DESC
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample data,

```
create table #temp(ACCT_ID int,  EFFDATE date, AMT int)
insert into #temp values
(1112 ,'12/30/2018',500 )
,(1112 ,'12/25/2018', 675 )
,(1112 ,'12/21/2018',  187 )
,(1112 ,'12/19/2018',  332 )
,(1112 ,'12/10/2018',   92 )
,( 1112 ,'12/3/2018', 300 )
,(2223 ,'12/29/2018',225 )
,(2223 ,'12/20/2018', 100 )
,(2223 ,'12/11/2018', 525 )
,(3334 ,'12/31/2018',1000 )
,(3334 ,'12/20/2018', 600 )
,(3334 ,'12/14/2018', 490 )
,(3334 ,'12/1/2018', 350 )
,(4445 ,'12/20/2018',  300 )
,(4445 ,'12/19/2018',  250 )
,(4445 ,'12/12/2018',  200 )
,(4445 ,'12/9/2018',  150)
,(4445 ,'12/6/2018',  100)
,(4445 ,'12/1/2018',  50)
```

Parameter,

```
declare @StartDate date='2018-12-01'
```

You need one small calendar table, since you need last 30 days or 20 days.

I have taken temp table.You can create calendar in any way you wish.

```
create  table #calendar(DateCol Date)
insert into #calendar 
select top 31  dateadd(day,ROW_NUMBER()over(order by (select null))-1,@StartDate) from sys.objects
```

Here on my script is important,

Now you need to create Account and calendar mapping table

```
create  table #Date_Acc_Map(ACCT_ID int ,dt date)
insert into #Date_Acc_Map (ACCT_ID,dt)
select ACCT_ID,DateCol from #calendar
cross apply(select ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by ACCT_ID order by ACCT_ID )rn
,  ACCT_ID from #temp where EFFDATE<=DateCol )ca
where rn=1
```

Last and important trick,

```
;with CTE as
(
select t.*,t1.AMT,t1.EFFDATE  from #Date_Acc_Map t
cross apply(select top 1 amt ,t1.EFFDATE from #temp t1 
where t.ACCT_ID=t1.ACCT_ID and t.dt>=t1.EFFDATE 
order by t1.EFFDATE desc )t1
)

----select * from CTE

select dt,sum(amt)Amt from CTE
group by dt
order by dt desc


drop table #temp
drop table #calendar
drop table #Date_Acc_Map
```

Code of `#Date_Acc_Map` can be further optimize depending upon volume of data in real table,and how much records to process at one time.

Comment: In query `select top 31`,  hard code of  `31` can be avoided,this was just sample,I do not have idea how you will pass parameter.